# Javascript toggle enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to toggle a "Please have Javascript enabled" warning?

Currently I've got something like this:

```
<div id='JSwarning'>ONLY SQUARES DON'T USE JAVASCRIPT</div>
```

to which I then apply `.style.display = "none"`.

This shows the warning on every page for a little while until it loads.  There must be a more graceful way. Can I do it with PHP?

(BTW, `get_browser()` is not the solution I'm looking for.)

//EDIT

Thanks everyone, that does the trick.  Incidentally, to get the page to validate (XHTML 1.0 Strict), I needed to place the child node(s) in a block container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script></script>
<noscript>Please enable Javascript.</noscript>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after the `noscript` tag:

```
<noscript>ONLY SQUARES DON'T USE JAVASCRIPT</noscript>
```

It's a browser convention, so you don't need to hide it when js is disabled (the browser does this automatically).

Answer (score 2):

use the noscript tag

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
<noscript>
    You need to enable javascript to view this page!
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does you apply this rule when DomContentLoaded is fired?
There is `<noscript>` too but it seems to me chrome ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to … not. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

JavaScript support is not a binary state. People can turn it on. People can turn it off. JS files can fail to load (because a server is down, or blocked). JS can be selectively enabled (e.g. with the Firefox NoScript extension).

Better to use progressive enhancement.